# Example of Group that is not Internal direct product under weaker condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, direct-product

I know definition of internal direct which is stronger that is

> $G$ is internal direct product of normal subgroup $N_i$ where $i$ is indexing upto $n$. Then
>
> 1. $G=N_1N_2N_3N_4N_5......N_n$
> 2. $N_i \cap (N_1....N_{i-1}N_{i+1}......N_n)=(e)$

It is clear that internal direct product is not possible in case of weaker condition of $N_i \cap N_j=(e)$. But I couldn't able to find counterexample to justify above.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, consider the Klein four group.  It has three two-element subgroups, and each pairwise intersection is trivial, but it is not a direct product of all three, or it would have order 8 rather than order 4.